# Problemas con diseño de aplicacion preguntas/respuestas

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Empecé a diseñar una aplicación en *Android Studio*, que consiste en preguntas y respuestas que pueden ser de múltiples opciones, de completar, etc. Pero como soy novato, no sé cuál es el método para resolver esto. ¿Debería usar un *Array* al estilo diccionario uniendo cada pregunta con su solución?

¿Debería ser así?

```
{Pregunta1:Sol1,Pregunta3:Sol3,Pregunta3:Sol3,etc}
```

Comment: Mmm piensa que si haces un diccionario con pregunta respuestas te estarían faltando las respuestas incorrectas que tengan que ver con la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo de diferentes maneras:

1. Una bbdd sql incrustada --> tendrás que contectarte con un cliente y hacer inserts y no te hará falta tocar el código de tu app.
2. Un fichero xml --> modificar el xml manualmente y leerlo desde la app
3. Un Array --> vas a tener que editar el código de tu app cada vez que quieras agregar preguntas y volver a exportar la app.

Si es una app profesional la más eficiente para mi es la primera, pero tardé un par de dias en hacer funcionar una bbdd incrustada; si no, el array va bien para comenzar.
El xml también creo que es una buena opción ,aunque ahora no se me ocurren pros y contras.

Comment: Conocrs bibliografía como para conocer de la primera opción?  Algo de Sql entiendo,  pero no de como implementarlo  como me dijiste

Comment: Es un poco diferente a cómo la recordaba, pero esta todo aca:

Comment: [tutorials](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html )[api](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/sql/package-summary.html)

Comment: Jeje, nunca me acuerdo que el 'enter' envia el comentario...Queria hacer un salto de linea. Si puedes modificalo.